# How to resolve bash: GRANT: command not found in PostgreSQL on debian OS?

Tags: debian, postgresql

I sent the below code for creating a new database and user in PostgreSQL

```
su - postgres

postgres@$ createuser green

Created Successfully

postgres@$ createdb greenland

Created Successfully

**Granting privileges on database**

postgres@$ GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE greenland TO green;
**-bash: GRANT: command not found**
```

As you see finally, I got a error message

**-bash: GRANT: command not found**

how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to establish a connection to the command-line interface of PostgreSQL first.

Run

```
psql
```

followed by

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE greenland TO green;
```

and exit the interface with

```
`\q`
```

again.

Or run the command from the shell via

```
psql -c 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE greenland TO green;'
```